# Limiting Query Result from a for each Loop

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I have three tables in a MySQL database, from which I am populating a dropdown select box. The problem arises because I want to use a line of the result as an option group label. However what I've achieved is the optgroup recurring with each option.

The tables are category, skill and skill_category. Category is a list of categories and their IDs (category_id, category_name); skill is a list of skills and their IDs (skill_id, skill_name) and skill_category assigns skills to categories (skill_id, category_id).

This is the code I'm using to retrieve and display the list of skills in a form to be grouped by their category names rather than a long list not visually broken up:

```
echo "<select name=\"skills\">";
echo "<option size =30 ></option>";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM skill " . 
       "LEFT OUTER JOIN skill_category ON skill.skill_id=skill_category.skill_id " .
       "LEFT OUTER JOIN category ON skill_category.category_id=category.category_id"
;
foreach ($myconnect->query($sql) as $row){
    echo " <optgroup  label='" . $row['category_name'] ."'>";
    echo "<option value='" . $row['skill_name'] ."'>" 
            . $row['skill_name'] .
         "</option>"
    ;
}
```

The question is how to begin the loop that fetches the  `$row['category_name']` along with the skill list but not have the category name atop every single skill. I believe the answer is staring me in the face but I can't see it. I don't want to manually write each optgroup and loop for each set of skills 
separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try storing the previously used category name in a variable and compare each iteration of the for loop. If the value is different, that means it's a category that hasn't been used before.

```
echo "<select name=\"skills\">";
echo "<option size=\"30\"></option>";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM skill LEFT OUTER JOIN skill_category ON skill.skill_id=skill_category.skill_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN category ON skill_category.category_id=category.category_id ORDER BY category_name";
$previousCategoryName = "";
foreach ($myconnect->query($sql) as $row) {
  if ($previousCategoryName != $row['category_name']) {
    if ($previousCategoryName != "") {
      echo "</optgroup>";
    }
    echo "<optgroup  label='" . $row['category_name'] ."'>";
    $previousCategoryName = $row['category_name'];
  }
  echo "<option value='" . $row['skill_name'] ."'>" . $row['skill_name'] ."</option>";
}
echo "</optgroup>";
```

Note I added the ORDER BY category_name into the query

Comment: don't forget to close the previous `<optgroup>` as well as the last one

Comment: Then their data is probably incorrect. I don't know the structure of the DB so i'm just going to write the code as he/she had it

Comment: Before thinking through the structure of the database I had stored the skills in different columns of the skill table and that is what caused EMPTY and NULL problems that I addressed with `if (!empty($row['bar']))`. Then it struck me to use a single column (with ID) and eliminate the untidy empty rows.

Comment: @Brett  my apologies. I incorrectly thanked Pevara for your posted contribution to the code. Thanks for your valuable help. Worked the first time. I had thought of storing something in a variable before the loop but for the life of me wasn't seeing how to implement it. Thanks a million. I may keep the ORDER BY as I had played with GROUP BY and ended up with a single group. No need to worry about empty spaces in the DB as the three table are straight lists (and associations) that make it simple to add skills and categories without modifying the script.

Comment: @MarkLee no worries Mark. glad i could help

Answer (score 0):

Add an `ORDER BY category.category_name` to the SQL statement. (Also consider adding additional expressions to the ORDER BY clause to make the result more deterministic, so the rows are returned in the same order each time the query runs.)

Before the loop, initialize a variable to hold "previous category_name".

Inside the loop, compare the return from `$row['category_name']` to the contents of the "previous category_name" variable.

Use a conditional test. If the values are different, then output the new category name. Otherwise, skip outputting the category_name.

Save the value returned from `$row['category_name']` into the "previous category_name" variable, so it's available for comparison the next time through the loop.